# What should be replication strategy across cross center 2 different cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I am looking for options to keep the data in sync between 2 cassandra cluster  across different region.

Comment: You mean two datacenters within a single cluster (use network topology replication)? or two clusters?

Comment: Thanks Chris for the comment. Actually i am looking for data sync options between 2 different clusters.                                                                                                           I know that table restore,snapshot are the options but is there any other option for continuous  data sync between 2 different cluster.